# Make floating li's span all over the ul width

Tags: html, css

Very simple **HTML:**

```
<div id="medium_ribbon">    
  <ul class="up_rectangles">
   <li id="first_up">
     <img src="img/home1.png" width="200" height="135" class="scalable">
   </li>
   <li id="second_up">
      <img src="img/home2.png" width="200" height="135" class="scalable">
   </li>
   <li id="third_up">
      <img src="img/home3.png" width="200" height="135" class="scalable">
   </li>
   <li id="fourth_up">
     <img src="img/home4.png" width="200" height="135" class="scalable">
   </li>    
  </ul>
</div><!--medium_ribbon-->
```

with the following **CSS:**

```
#medium_ribbon {    
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#172236;
  overflow:auto;
}
.up_rectangles {
  max-width: 1105px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: medium solid #F00;    
}
.up_rectangles li {
  line-height: 200px;   
  width: 23.7%;    
  background-color: #C8CACF; 
  float:left;
  margin-right: 1.3%;
  border:solid thin blue;
}
.up_rectangles>li:last-child {  
  margin-right:0;           
}
.up_rectangles img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

You may see it live at http://users.sch.gr/ellhn/.

**My question** is why the fourth box does not go to the end of the red border line as to span all over the ul width. The sum of the percentages excluding the li borders is 98.7%. The remaining 1.3% is supposed to be given to the eight (left-right-left-right...)borders. Why the whole ul width is not filled? By trying to increase the border width (from thin to medium) the fourth box loses its position and goes to the next line. I've also tried using percentages for the border width,it did not work...
Is there any way to span my li's till the very right end?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your calculation is right? If I set `.up_rectangles li {
margin-right: 1.6%; }` it seems to work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.up_rectangles li{margin-right: 1.45%}
.up_rectangles > li:last-child { float: right; margin-right: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.up_rectangles>li:last-child { margin-right:0;border:solid 2px #C8CACF !important;}
```

## or

```
.up_rectangles>li:last-child {margin-right:0;border:solid 0px #C8CACF !important;float:right;}
```